# Counting the occurence of each character in multidimensional list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to count the occurrence of each character in this list below:

```
messages=['It is certain',
          'It is decidedly so',
          'Yes definitely',
          'Reply hazy try again',
          'Ask again later',
          'Concentrate and ask again',
          'My reply is no',
          'Outlook not so good',
          'Very doubtful']
```

My code is this:

```
a=dict((letter,messages.count(letter))for letter in set(messages))
print(a)
```

Output is:

```
{'Yes definitely': 1, 'Very doubtful': 1, 'It is decidedly so': 1, 'Outlook not so good': 1, 'Reply hazy try again': 1, 'It is certain': 1, 'My reply is no': 1, 'Concentrate and ask again': 1, 'Ask again later': 1}
```

This is counting of each element in list instead I want count of each character.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, one hacky way to do this is:

```
messages=['It is certain','It is decidedly so','Yes definitely','Reply hazy try again','Ask again later','Concentrate and ask again','My reply is no','Outlook not so good','Very doubtful']

characters = list(''.join(messages).replace(" ","").lower())

characters.sort()
from itertools import groupby
count = {key:len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(characters)}

print(count)

{'a': 13, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 7, 'e': 12, 'f': 2, 'g': 4, 'h': 1, 'i': 12, 'k': 3, 'l': 7, 'm': 1, 'n': 10, 'o': 11, 'p': 2, 'r': 7, 's': 8, 't': 11, 'u': 3, 'v': 1, 'y': 9, 'z': 1}
```